# Gradient involved commutator in $\phi^4$ theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, hamiltonian-formalism, commutator

In a phi fourth theory, the Hamiltonian density is:

$$\mathcal{H}=\frac{1}{2}\pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4$$

Now I impose the usual equal time canonical commutation relations for fields ($\hbar=1$)

$$[\phi(\vec{x}),\pi(\vec{y})]=i \delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{y})$$

where

$$\pi=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial (\dot{\phi})} \equiv \dot{\phi}$$

Heisenberg equation of motion for the field is just the definition of the conjugate momentum

$$\frac{d}{dt}\phi(\vec{x},t)=\pi(\vec{x},t) $$

and for $\pi(\vec{x})$ I have to calculate the commutator (not writing time dependence)

$$[H,\pi(\vec{x},t)]=\int d^3x'\left[\frac{1}{2}\pi^2(\vec{x}')+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2(\vec{x}')+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2(\vec{x}')+\frac{\lambda}{4!}\phi^4(\vec{x}'),\pi(\vec{x}) \right] $$

First term gives zero, third and fourth terms give $i\left(m^2\phi(\vec{x})+\frac{\lambda}{3!}\phi^3(\vec{x})\right)$

My question is, how can I calculate

$$\frac{1}{2}\int d^3x' [(\nabla \phi)^2(\vec{x}'),\pi(\vec{x})] $$

As an analogy with the integral of the commutator is the commutator of the integral, may I write $\nabla \phi^2=\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \phi$  and integrate by parts? How can I show that that is true?

Comment: You could do integration by parts but I wouldn't bother (it would be easiest to do it in the formula for the Hamiltonian before doing the commutator). Rather I'd start by working out the commutator for the individual components of the gradient: $[\partial_{i'} \phi(\vec{x}'), \pi(\vec{x})]$ where by $\partial_{i'}$ I mean $\partial_{x'},\partial_{y'},\partial_{z'}$. Note that you can pull the spatial derivatives out of the commutator. You can use this result and some standard identities to simplify the expresion you have.

Comment: $\partial_{i'}[\phi(\vec{x}'),\pi(\vec{x})]=\partial_{i'}i\delta^{3}(\vec{x}- \vec{x}')]$ As $(\nabla_{'} \phi(\vec{x}'))^2=\partial_{i}\partial^{i}(x)$ but I'm not quite sure

Comment: Yep. The gradient just comes out. (It doesn't work with time derivatives because $\dot{\phi}=\pi$, but space derivatives are nothing special.)

Comment: @Michael Brown Sorry, I typed intro too fast and couldn't edit my comment in time. I see that I get second derivative of a delta, does that means that when I do the integral, I get the second derivative without the integral?

Comment: Yes you get the derivative of a delta function. Let's write it out carefully here: $[(\nabla\phi)^2(x),\pi(y)]=\nabla\phi(x)\cdot[\nabla\phi(x),\pi(y)]+[\nabla\phi(x),\pi(y)]\nabla\phi(x)$. Simplifying:$\nabla\phi(x)\cdot\nabla_x[\phi(x),\pi(y)]+\nabla_x[\phi(x),\pi(y)]\nabla\phi(x)=2\nabla\phi(x)\cdot\nabla_x i\delta(x-y)$. So you see a derivative of a delta function in some integral: $\int \mathrm{d}x f(x) \partial \delta(x-y)$. How would you deal with that?

Comment: It is the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $x-y=0$, $f'(y)$

Comment: There's a minus sign from integration by parts $-f'(y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formal computation. First note that: $$[A^2,B]=AAB-ABA+ABA-BAA=A[A,B]+[A,B]A.$$

Also: $$[\frac{\partial}{\partial z'}\phi (\mathbf x'),\pi (\mathbf x)]=\frac{\partial}{\partial z'}[\phi (\mathbf x'),\pi (\mathbf x)]=\frac{\partial}{\partial z'}i\delta ^3 (\mathbf x ' -\mathbf x )=i\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z'}  (z'-z)\delta(x'-x)\delta (y'-y).$$

Recall that the derivative of a distribution $T$ is defined by: $$(T',f)=-(T,f').$$

So:

$$[(\frac{\partial}{\partial z'}\phi (\mathbf x'))^2,\pi (\mathbf x)]=2i\frac{\partial \delta}{\partial z'}  (z'-z)\delta(x'-x)\delta (y'-y)\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z'} (\mathbf x ')$$
and: $$\int \text {d} ^3 \mathbf x '[(\frac{\partial}{\partial z'}\phi (\mathbf x'))^2,\pi (\mathbf x)]=-2i\frac{\partial ^2\phi}{\partial z ^2} (\mathbf x ).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int d^{3}\vec{x}'[\nabla\phi(\vec{x}',t)\cdot{\nabla\phi(\vec{x}',t)},\pi(\vec{x},t)]$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'},\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{y}',t)}{\partial y'},\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{z}',t)}{\partial z'}\Big)\cdot{\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'},\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{y}',t)}{\partial y'},\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{z}',t)}{\partial z'}\Big)},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\Big)^{2}+\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{y}',t)}{\partial y'}\Big)^{2}+\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{z}',t)}{\partial z'}\Big)^{2},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\Big)^{2},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]+\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{y}',t)}{\partial y'}\Big)^{2},\pi(\vec{y},t)\bigg]+\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{z}',t)}{\partial z'}\Big)^{2},\pi(\vec{z},t)\bigg]$.

Let's consider only the first commutator.

$\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\Big(\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\Big)^{2},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]$

$\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}+\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\bigg[\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]$.

Let's consider only the first commutator.

$\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'},\pi(\vec{x},t)\bigg]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\pi(\vec{x},t)-\pi(\vec{x},t)\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}\bigg]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\bigg[\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\{\phi(\vec{x}',t)\pi(\vec{x},t)\}-\phi(\vec{x}',t)\frac{\partial\pi(\vec{x},t)}{\partial x'}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\{\pi(\vec{x},t)\phi(\vec{x}',t)\}+\frac{\partial\pi(\vec{x},t)}{\partial x'}\phi(\vec{x}',t)\bigg]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}[\phi(\vec{x}',t),\pi(\vec{x},t)]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=\int d^{3}\vec{x}'\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}[i\delta^{(3)}(\vec{x}'-\vec{x},t)]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}[i]\frac{\partial\phi(\vec{x}',t)}{\partial x'}$

$=0$.

Similarly, all other terms are zero.

So, the answer is zero.